Have a drush script which replaces some code then calls function to return version of new code, it doesn't see new code, how get it to see new code?
I have a drush script which basically updates a module by extracting a tar file.  The script then runs a php function which goes out to the code tree and reads the version from one of the files.  Unfortunately, it returns the version from before the tar.  Is there a way to get it to sort of refresh the env so it sees the new code when it runs the function?
I can do a drush_shell_exec and read the file and see it has the new version, but that makes for slightly messy convoluted code.
Yes, I know, there are standard ways to update a module and this isn't one of them.  Old legacy code, too much to change to do "correctly", etc., etc.
Not that I expected it to work, I did try clearing the caches after the code tree gets changed.  I tried doing a drush_shell_exec(php -r 'include "path to file"; function call;') but that doesn't set up the php environment appropriately and returns nothing.  I put the command the exec is issuing into a string so it was really drush_shell_exec("$cmd").
drush version 8.4.12.
php version 8.1.2
